# Secure vs. Secured

Tags: grammar

Let's say I have an advertisement for a parking garage. This parking garage has heat, and it has security.

The options are:

1. Heated and Secured Parking
2. Heated and Secure Parking

Which is more correct? I can see cases for both.

Comment: What cases do you see for both?

Comment: 2 is better.  The connection between "secured" and "has security" is no longer obvious in current-day English (IMO).

Comment: @GregLee I felt the opposite way at first, but the more I say/read it, the more "Secure" sounds correct.

Comment: @KevinWorkman "Heated and Secured" makes sense because it is heated with heat and secured with security. "Heated and Secure" makes sense because as GregLee stated, the connection between "secured" and "has security" is no longer obvious in current-day english.

Comment: I'll play the pedant here. **secured** means that it has been made secure at some point in the past, but may no longer be **secure** in the present. Whereas **secure** describes the state of the garage currently, which is more relevant for the parker. I don't see a case for #1 unless you're hoping for some kind of loophole in a court of law. I would even take out the "and" and have "heated secure parking".

Comment: @MartinKrzywinski I'd argue that that's not always the case. Take "heated" for example. Heated in this case obviously does not mean it was heated in the past and not anymore.

Comment: "warm secure parking", how's that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say either:

1. *Heated Secure Parking* if *secure parking* is a distinct category of parking that gives has a distinct meaning from parking which happens to be secure but that it is secure in a specific way - for instance, parking in a private underground car park with no public access. In this case, *secure parking* is functioning as a compound noun and *heated* as an adjective.
2. *Secure, Heated Parking* if I wanted to convey that I was selling parking that has both heat and security, especially if competitors have only one or ther other. In the case *secure* and *heated* are adjectives and should go in the more natural order.

I would not say "secured parking" because "secured" tends to be used (in the physical world) to mean someone has taken particular actions taken to counter a specific risk (without implication of success), e.g. used of which have been tied or bolted to prevent movement, which is not really the sense of 'security' you want to convey: the parking spots have not merely *been secured* but *are inherently secure*.

I would not use the *and* except if there is some other grammatical context forcing it.

Comment: Secure parking as a compound noun is what sold it to me, thanks. That's my situation. I've gone with Heated Secure Parking as you suggested. Removing the "and" was a good suggestion as well. Thanks!